# having issues Setting Image caching in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Im using firebase storage, while uploading images to it i also pass in cacheControl pair. Im having trouble on getting the image to cache locally when i download.

Any help pls ..

```
doupload(event: FileList) {
    const file = event.item(0);
    if (file.type.split('/')[0] !== 'image') {
      console.error('unsupported file type:(');
      return;
    }

    const path = `test/${new Date().getTime()}_${file.name}`;
    const fileRef = this.storage.ref(path);
    const customMetadata = { app: 'Namma Tiruppur', cacheControl: 'public,max-age=150000', };
    this.task = this.storage.upload(path, file, { customMetadata });
    this.percentage = this.task.percentageChanges();
    this.snapshot = this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      tap(snap => {
        if (snap.bytesTransferred === snap.totalBytes) {
          this.newsImg = path;

        }
      })
    );

    this.snapshot.pipe(finalize(() => this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL())).subscribe();

  }
```